# Edit pipeline query in azure data factory V1 manually

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How to edit pipeline and data sets query in azure data factory v1 manually

With the recent changes in ui of azure portal.. we are not able to edit pipeline query manually. Is there any alternate way to edit pipeline query manually  ??

Comment: What's your source and sink dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and pipeline still could be edit now.

I created a copy active in Data Factory v1.

Choose the Monitor&Manage action in Data Factory Overview.

[image]

Edit the pipeline manually: AUTHOR--->Resource exploer---> right click pipeline/dataset--->edit
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: how you created copy active in Data Factory v1 ?

Comment: Just using the Copy data(preview). You can edit the data set query by the pipeline Edit or dataset edit. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @steve, Can you  accept it as answer? Thank you very much!

Comment: I only see options to "Open pipeline", "Resume pipeline", "Pause pipeline", and "Pause and terminate pipeline". Did they remove the Edit option? For the life of me I cannot figure out how to edit activities in a v1 pipeline.